# modifying django admin template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm writing application in python using Django Framework and I'm trying to figure out if there is a possibility to modify existing django admin app templates (change_form.html, base_site.html...) for a specific module. In the folder project I have already put the templates/admin directory where I modified admin app templates, but for one specific module I would like to use different template. The specific module is in a separate app.

I would be very grateful if you could let me know how can I achieve that or at least point me to the documentation where I can find it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override on a [ModelAdmin level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options), rather than just overriding the templates by templates/ namespace.

**Edit:** I just noticed you were looking to possibly have multiple versions of non-object-specific template pages (at least base_site.html) per-module. I'm not sure you will be able to do that without [customizing AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class). You could additionally register multiple admin sites, though the usefulness there will depend on your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by overriding the specific template at the level you want it to customize it. For example if you want to modify **change_form.html** for your app you can create (or copy the change_form.html from contrib/admin/templates...) a template in **templates/admin/yourapp/change_form.html**. For a model in your app, you can place it in **templates/admin/yourapp/yourmodel/change_form.html**. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975763/modifying-django-admin-template)

From the link above:

> For example, if we wanted to add a tool to the change list view for all the models in an app named my_app, we would copy contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html to the templates/admin/my_app/ directory of our project, and make any necessary changes.
>
> If we wanted to add a tool to the change list view for only a specific model named ‘Page’, we would copy that same file to the templates/admin/my_app/page directory of our project.